# Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Group in autoscaling group over JdbcLockRegistry

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to create a consumer application that is using spring cloud stream to consume events from a Kinesis stream.

My consumer application is running inside an AWS autoscaling group and I would like it to scale up and down at any point without affecting the number of instances that can process a given entry in the stream. More specifically I would like to have at most one instance processing an event from the stream at any point in time.

After reading the documentation I thought that this functionality can be achieved using consumer groups, the Kinesis binder is even offering its own implementation of MetaDataStore and LockRegistry build on top of DynamoDB.

Since I do not want to introduce DynamoDB only for holding the locks and the metadata, I though I could achieve the same result using the Jdbc equivalent implementations, using a predefined group.

After my initial test I saw that the jdbc stores were used as expected but when I increase the instances on the ASG I noticed that the messages get consumed twice (once from each instance) instead of what I would expect after reading the documentation.

My properties are:

> spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=stream
>   spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=group
>   spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json

The configuration for the lock registry leader e.t.c.:

```
@Bean
public DefaultLockRepository lockRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public LockRegistry lockRegistry(LockRepository lockRepository) {
    return new JdbcLockRegistry(lockRepository);
}

@Bean
public LockRegistryLeaderInitiator leaderInitiator(LockRegistry lockRegistry) {
    LockRegistryLeaderInitiator lockRegistryLeaderInitiator = new LockRegistryLeaderInitiator(lockRegistry);
    lockRegistryLeaderInitiator.setPublishFailedEvents(true);
    return lockRegistryLeaderInitiator;
}

@Bean
public MetadataStore metadataStore(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}
```

I have one stream with one shard on my Kinesis at the moment.

I have tried adding more shard (up to 4), I have tried configuring the concurrency via the application properties.

I can see that the metadata store is populated as expected on my database and that the consumer is keeping the state as expected, but I also see multiple entries on the int_lock table which I did not expect to see (i.e. I expected to see only one client registered but I see multiple).

So my questions are:

1. Has anyone configured a consumer using a jdbc registry?
2. Is there any issues with my setup?
3. Since the documentation is not really clear, is the lock registry locking access to the Kinesis stream?

I am pretty sure I am missing something on the conceptual side but I did not find anything in the documentation, [the closest to my issue was this issue reported on github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1342)
But this confused me even more about the expected configurations.
Also it is not clear how instanceIndex and instanceCount are supposed to work in an ASG environment

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with your configuration. The `KinesisMessageChannelBinder` really expects a `ConcurrentMetadataStore` and `LockRegistry` beans. And it already doesn't matter what implementations you use.

You don't need a `LockRegistryLeaderInitiator` though. It isn't used in the binder and might do some extra unexpected work for you.

You need to be sure though, that `DataSource` is a shared RDBMS between all your instances. Also you need to be sure that `group` option is really the same for all the instances.

Also the locking logic is really based on a key like:

```
this.consumerGroup + ":" + stream + ":" + shardId
```

So, no ideas what may be wrong in your configuration yet...

Comment: Thank you for the response. the DB is shared and the properties same for all instances, I will try to remove the leader initiator and report back if this had any effect.
Just for me to understand though because the documentation is not really clear about it and while going over the github issues I got even more confused, is the group synchronisation dependent on the number of shards? should I set the instanceIndex and count properties? is the synchronisation happening on the application layer from the lock registry?

Comment: Synchronization happens per shard in a group. So, if that is a new group and the same shard, then they are not synchronized. The `instanceIndex` and `count` don't make anything with synchronization. They are for the case when you would like to distribute shards manually. Not sure in your last question, but it is indeed that `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` tries to perform locking for its shards all the time.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response, just tried again without having the leader election and it seems that I am still getting the messages twice, is there an example that you can point me that is actually showcasing this behaviour? 
Also any suggestions or ideas what could go wrong?
Is there a way I can test those locally?

Comment: I test it locally against `kinesalite`, but I heard there is something like `localstack`: https://github.com/localstack/localstack. The DB can be any you can run locally as well.

Comment: I have tried connecting locally from my PC and I can see that the lock is utilized when the KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter bean is started. 
I have connected another PC on the same stream and after that I triggered a message, while my PC had the lock and I could see it on the DB, both consumers got invoked, I will try using a Redis lock to test this but do you know if there are any successful implementations of this using JDBC lock?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of such a sample. I can try to implement something simple later against a local MySQL...

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I was browsing through the source and it seems to me that the actual polling from the kinesis stream is happening from ShardConsumer, the lock is acquired from the ShardConsumerManager which creates a ShardConsumer (after getting the lock for the shard) and leaves the ConsumerDispatcher actually call the thread.
I was expecting the lock to be re-acquired (or at least checked) before every consuming event from the shard, to me it seems that the lock is acquired (also seen on the DB as I have one entry) but after the acquisition all the instances pull the info

Comment: Please, share with me as simple project as possible against local MySQL and Kinesalite and also instruction how to reproduce. Or people don't use this consumer group feature, or something fishy is going on with your solution. I mean I haven't heard complains on the matter from community yet. And it really doesn't matter what kind of distributed locking implementation we use...